# How to fix, uncaught typeerror object is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an inhertied application and getting error (Uncaught typeerror: Object is not a function) on this line of code in JavaScript

```
var lobj_css = new Object(document.styleSheets("cssName"));
```

[image: Uncaught typeerror: Object is not a function]

It does work in IE8 and no errors but not anything above IE8 and neither in Google chrome.

Comment: Why are you editing stylesheets using javascript? If you want to change the style on an element, just do `el.style[name] = value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple enough to do some troubleshooting.

Try the offending line, on its own, in a standalone web page, JS Bin, or fiddle, **[like this](http://jsbin.com/rubus/1/edit)**

Same result. Now try breaking the assignment out separately, and commenting out the `Object()` constructor, so you can see if the `document.styleSheets` call is causing your problem.

```
var stylesheets = document.styleSheets("cssName");
// var lobj_css = new Object(stylesheets);
```

Result:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Looks like there's something about the `document.styleSheets("cssName")` that's causing a problem. Let's hit the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets

> The Document.styleSheets read-only property returns a StyleSheetList of StyleSheet objects for stylesheets explicitly linked into or embedded in a document.

And the example on that page:

```
var styleSheetList = document.styleSheets;
```

...sure doesn't look like the code from your example.

Looks to me like the legacy code is using a non-standard call to `document.styleSheets` that is implemented as a function instead of a readonly property. You'll have to shim it if you want to keep the code as-is, but I'd recommend fixing it to be standard. Perhaps you can iterate over the list of stylesheets until you find the one that matches `cssName`.